# Click once with with Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $( "#product_filters_form_sizes_medeiumnnarrow" ).click()
  $('menu.pills').on('click', 'a', function(event){
    $pill = $(this);
    $('form.product_filters_form')
      .find("input[value='"+$pill.data('filterId')+"']")
      .attr('checked', false).trigger('change');
  })
});
```

It does exactly what I need it do, which is to select `'#product_filters_form_sizes_mediumnarrow'` only issue is it keeps on clicking and the pages reloads each time.

My questions is: is there a way to only click once?

Thank you and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  <li class="product_filter input required" id="product_filters_form_sizes_input"><fieldset class="choices"><legend class="label"><label>Sizes</label></legend><input id="product_filters_form_sizes_none" name="product_filters_form[sizes][]" type="hidden" value=""><ol class="choices-group"><li class="choice"><label for="product_filters_form_sizes_mediumnarrow"><input id="product_filters_form_sizes_mediumnarrow" name="product_filters_form[sizes][]" type="checkbox" value="medium/narrow"><i class="icon checked-indicator"></i>MEDIUM/NARROW</label></li>
```

Comment: I think you mean it clicks once, reloads the page, and then clicks once, reloads the page... you see the problem? ;)

Comment: What does "#product_filters_form_sizes_mediumnarrow" do? does it posts back the form? Perhaps, u can use `$('#product_filters_form_sizes_mediumnarrow').focus()` instead?

Comment: as @wwwmarty said you need some condition before calling this .click() script. In this way you have infinite loop.

Comment: I tried with `.one` and didn't work for me

Comment: You need to be more specific on what happens when `product_filters_form_sizes_mediumnarrow ` gets clicked.

Comment: Do you want the page to reload at all? What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: I need it get clicked only once when the page loads, I don't need it to keep reloading

Comment: Do you need it to reload at all?  Because when it does it'll just run from the beginning again. Not sure why it reloads the page in the first place...

Comment: I didn't post full my full script, looking at it, see updated code,  on click second part gets executed, probably why its repeating, any way this can be refactored so that it doesn't go into an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

if you need a function that does something once in jQuery it's called one.
you're probably looking for:

```
$('#product_filters_form_sizes_mediumnarrow').one('click');
```

your problem is probably happening because a reload is happening and this is the line that immediately happens.

so my question to you buddy is what does the click actually do?
i guess it's a form submission.

Comment: and how would this help if page reloads each time?

Comment: That's the first thing I tried and it doesn't work and yes it's a form submission